# How to convert in Notepad++ using regular expressions?

Tags: notepad++, regex

How to convert `«Ctrl+(any letter)» Any words` to `«Ctrl+(any letter)» — Any words`?

For example. I need like this:

```
«Ctrl+T» Free transform
«Ctrl+D» Deselect selections
etc.
```

Convert to:

```
«Ctrl+T» — Free transform
«Ctrl+D» — Deselect selections
etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Find what: `(«Ctrl\+.»\s)`
- Replace with: `$1-`
- Search mode: `Regular expression`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to search for

```
»
```

and replace it with

```
» —
```

P.S. there is space ( ) at the end on both strings